# Ayuda, Como validar los campos de un formulario para realizar la búsqueda en BD con java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring, servicio

Tengo un formulario con 6 campos, dos de ellos son de tipo calendario, lo que debe hacer la pantalla es buscar informacion en la BD y mostrarlos en un archivo de excel dependiendo los filtros ingresados, no es necesario llenar todos los 6 campos, únicamente que estén llenos los dos campos de fecha, esos si son obligatorios, tengo el siguiente código para esa validación

Tengo el siguiente código en la implementación del servicio:

```
public List<Factura> realizaBusqueda(FacturaVO facturaVO){
       List<Factura> listaFact;
       if("".equals(facturaVO.getClave()))
           facturaVO.setClave(null);
       if("".equals(facturaVO.getNombreProd()))
           facturaVO.setNombreProd(null);
       if("".equals(facturaVO.getNombreCliente()))
           facturaVO.setNombreCliente(null);
       if(!"".equals(facturaVO.getClaveId()) && !"".equals(facturaVO.getFecIni()) && !"".equals(facturaVO.getFecFin()))
       {
           listaFact = realizaBusquedaFacturaRepository.findByParameters(facturaVO.getClaveId, facturaVO.getFecIni, facturaVO.getFecFin);
       }else{
           listaFact = realizaBusquedaFacturaRepository.findByParametersOtro(facturaVO.getClave(), facturaVO.getNombreProd(),facturaVO.getNombreCliente(),facturaVO.getClaveId, facturaVO.getFecIni, facturaVO.getFecFin);
       }

       return listaFact;
   }
```

Tengo los siguientes registros en mi BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo en mi pantalla ingreso en el campo de `ClaveId = 560`

y en el campo `FechaIni = 28/06/18`

y en el `FechFin= 03/07/18`,  me arroja esos registros y es correcto

pero si ingreso  `ClaveId = 560`

`FechaIni = 28/06/18`

`FechFin = 03/07/18`,

y en el campo `NombreProd = Producto2`

me vuelven a salir los mismos registros y es incorrecto por que deberia de mostrar solo el registro con el nombre de producto 2

y haciendo la prueba si solo ingreso los datos

`FechaIni = 28/06/18`

`FechFin= 03/07/18`,

y en el campo `NombreProd = Producto2`

si muestra ese único registro con el Producto2 lo cual es correcto pero debería de funcionar si hago la búsqueda también con el claveId u otro campo y no se porque NO lo esta haciendo.

¿Cómo debo de hacer mis validaciones para que salgan correctamente los datos?

Ya sea que se ingresen los campos completos para la búsqueda, o los dos campos de fecha que son obligatorios mas otro campo por ejemplo el de `claveId`

Ojala me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Cuando rellenas el campo NombreProd con "Producto2", al pasar por los if, ¿te detecta que está relleno ese campo o te lo pasa a null?

Comment: @Pablo, si, cuando lleno los dos Campos de fecha y el campo de NombreProd pasa por el  “else” y pinta el dato que ingrese y si también lleno el campo d claveId pasa por el if y también lo pinta